# How do I get results from MYSQL query and store it in a variable using C?

Tags: mysql, c, variables, store

I used "select" for my mysql query. Now, I don't know how I will get the result and store it in a user-defined variable.  I am using C programming language. Thanks

Comment: Can You show us Your Code ?

Answer (score -1):

I'd check this out
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933972.aspx

Opening OpenSqlFilestream should allow to query and read the database